# Como se hace para crear o copiar un archivo a la carpeta download?

Tags: genexus

En un pequeño desarrollo de una app para android, necesito escribir un archivo en la carpeta "/storage/emulated/0/Download"..  y no encuentro ninguna manera de poder hacerlo desde gx...

hasta ahora lo hacia especificando la ruta con el metodo
&File.Source = !'/storage/emulated/0/Download/archivo.ext' y luego con el &File.Create()...    esto sabiendo que colocando por hardcode la ruta no es lo mas recomendable, pero no hay ninguna funcion dentro de gx que devuelva dicha carpeta..   de todas maneras lo tenia resuelto asi y funcionaba bien....
pero ahora, no se si debido el reciente U5 o al nivel de api30 ya no es posible hacerlo...  en ejecucion da siempre error de permisos de acceso..

Puedo escribir perfectamente en direcciones construidas con los metodos Directoy (Directory.ApplicationDataPath, Directory.CacheFilesPath, etc)... pero son direcciones que no son visibles para el usuario. Necesito que el archivo queda grabado en una carpeta que el usuario pueda acceder y visualizar desde otras aplicaciones.

Algo que me desconcierta mucho, es que especificando la ruta por hardcode como nombre anteriormente, funciona bien cuando lo pruebo en un emulador de android studio... pero en dispositivos reales me da error...
Analizandolos con el logcat, dice permision denied...

No encuentro como resolverlo...

Alguien me puede decir una manera de escribir o copiar un archivo en la carpeta descargas de un dispositivo android?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: El access denied se debe a la target api 30 y sus restricciones de seguridad. En Genexus beta encontraras un nuevo método, SaveToFolder en la FilesApi para hacer esto. Sino, puedes hacer un EO usando MediaStore.

Comment: Muy bueno, suponía que pronto lo irían a contemplar. Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola @fpanizza..   Aun no veo que esto esté implementado en los últimos upgrades... hay alguna fecha posible?

Comment: Esta en el canal de beta. Actualmente esta en revision/test. Esperamos se incluya en el proximo upgrade (v17u8 probablemente).